# Beginner Type Errors using Filter

Tags: haskell

I'm just starting to use Haskell, and I'm having what most of you reading would probably consider a beginner blunder.

Consider a list of tuples myTupleList = [(3,6),(4,8),(1,3)]

Nice. I wrote this function to return the list of tuples in which the second element in the first tuple, is double the first element:
(Ex using myTupleList: double myTupleList , which returns [(3,6),(4,8)] )

```
double [] = []
double (x:xs)
   |(snd x) == 2 * (fst x) = x: double xs
   |otherwise              = double xs
```

Now I'm sure this isn't the prettiest function in the world, but it works. The problem now is adapting it to use filter. This is my current attempt:

```
double [] = []
double xs = filter ((2 * (fst(head xs))) == (snd(head xs))) xs
```

To my undestanding, filter recieves two arguments: a boolean expression and a list. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘(a, a) -> Bool’
              with actual type ‘Bool’
• Possible cause: ‘(==)’ is applied to too many arguments
  In the first argument of ‘filter’, namely
    ‘((2 * (fst (head xs))) == (snd (head xs)))’
  In the expression:
    filter ((2 * (fst (head xs))) == (snd (head xs))) xs
  In an equation for ‘double’:
      double xs = filter ((2 * (fst (head xs))) == (snd (head xs))) xs
• Relevant bindings include
    xs :: [(a, a)] (bound at Line 9, Column 8)
    double :: [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)] (bound at Line 8, Column 1)
```

I'm sure this is just some silly error or limitation of Haskell as a functional language that I'm not accustomed to or understanding properly, but it would be great to get some help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`filter` expects a function `a -> Bool`, but `(2 * (fst(head xs))) == (snd(head xs))` is not a function that maps an element to a `Bool`, but simply a `Bool`. It does not make much sense here to use `head x`, you use the parameter to get "access" to the element:

```
double :: (Eq a, Num a) => [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)]
double xs = filter (\x -> 2 * fst x == snd x) xs
```

You can use pattern matching to unpack the 2-tuple and thus no longer need `fst` and `snd`. Furthermore you can perform an *η-reduction*, and thus remove `xs` both in the head and the body of `double` in this case:

```
double :: (Eq a, Num a) => [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)]
double = filter (\(a, b) -> 2 * a == b)
```

This gives us:

```
Prelude> double [(3,6),(4,8),(1,3)]
[(3,6),(4,8)]
```

We can even make the predicate *point-free*:

```
double :: (Eq a, Num a) => [(a, a)] -> [(a, a)]
double = filter (uncurry ((==) . (2 *)))
```

Comment: You lost me on that last answer, but I understand the other two. So " \x " creates like a abstract variable, for lack of better words? A template for filter to follow I guess? Thank you very much for this answer!

Comment: @TypicalMoronlmao: If you write `\x -> 2 * x` for example, you create a function that maps values `x` to `2 * x` in that case. Here we thus make a function that for example maps a 2-tupe `(a, b)` on `2 * a == b`. It is thus a predicate that decides whether to retain the value.

Comment: @TypicalMoronlmao As an additional example, the definition `f x y = x*x + y` is equivalent to `f = \x y -> x*x + y`, that is "`f` is equal to the function which takes `x` and `y` as arguments and returns `x*x + y`. This `\x y -> ...` is called an "anonymous function" (since we haven't given it a name, yet), or a "lambda" (historical reasons, and the \ is meant to represent a greek lambda)